# Простой RegExp

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Здравствуй уважаемый %user%**

Если не сложно, напиши мне пожалуйста регулярное выражение для такого формата:

```
<Number 0><Start 18:28:50>
<Number 7><Lap1 18:53:08>
<Number 99556><Fin 18:53:08>
```

из строки мне нужно вытащить в переменную число после "`<Number` ", слово после второй открывающейся скобки (в примере это `Start`, `Lap1`, `Fin`, но может быть все что угодно) и время (например `18:28:50`).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так может те просто вырезать символы в строках и все

```
$seach=array('Number','<','>')
str_replace($seach,'',$srt);
$srt - входная строка
```

Comment: Спасибо за простое решение!
жаль плюсик не могу поставить(